# Proper use of structures and pointers

Tags: c, struct, scanf

I have to declare a vector with the "struct" type which, for every n students, it creates a value for the group that student belongs to (which is like a counter), their names and their grades.

The program has to output the name of the students with the highest grade found in these groups. I have to allocate the vector on the heap (I only know the theoretical explanation for heap, but I have no idea how to apply it) and I have to go through the vector using pointers.

For example if I give n the value 4, there will be 4 students and the program will output the maximum grade together with their names as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFPq0.png).

This will output Ana 10 and Eva 10.

I gave it a try, but I have no idea how to expand it or fix it so I appreciate all the help I can get with explanations if possible on the practical application of heap and pointers in this type of problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct students {
    int group;
    char name[20];
    int grade;
};

int main()
{
    int v[100], n, i;
    scanf("%d", n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
          v[i].group = i;
          scanf("%s", v[i].name);
          scanf("%d", v[i].grade);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
          printf("%d", v[i].group);
          printf("%s", v[i].name);
          printf("%d", v[i].grade);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here I was just trying to create the vector, nothing works though..

Comment: `scanf("%d", n);` --> `scanf("%d", &n);` and `scanf("%d", v[i].grade);` --> `scanf("%d", &v[i].grade);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the standalone array `v[100]`, with an array of structs referencing your structure:

```
struct students v[100];
```

However, if you want to use [`malloc`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm) to allocate memory on the heap, you will need to do something like this:

```
struct students *students = malloc(n * sizeof(struct students));

/* Check void* return pointer from malloc(), just to be safe */
if (students == NULL) {
     /* Exit program */
}
```

and [`free`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_free.htm) the requested memory from `malloc()` at the end, like this:

```
free(students);
students = NULL;
```

Additionally, adding to @Sourav Ghosh's answer, it is also good to check the return value of `scanf()`, especially when dealing with integers.

Instead of simply:

```
scanf("%d", &n);
```

A more safe way is this:

```
if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
     /* Exit program */
}
```

With all this said, your program could look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NAMESTRLEN 20

typedef struct {  /* you can use typedef to avoid writing 'struct student' everywhere */
    int group;
    char name[NAMESTRLEN+1];
    int grade;
} student_t;

int
main(void) {
    int n, i;

    printf("Enter number of students: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
        printf("Invalid input.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    student_t *students = malloc(n * sizeof(*students));
    if (!students) {
        printf("Cannot allocate memory for %d structs.\n", n);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        students[i].group = i;

        printf("Enter student name: ");
        scanf("%20s", students[i].name);

        printf("Enter students grade: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &(students[i].grade)) != 1) {
            printf("Invalid grade entered.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    printf("\nStudent Information:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Group: %d Name: %s Grade: %d\n", 
                students[i].group, 
                students[i].name, 
                students[i].grade);
    }

    free(students);
    students = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your detailed response, I will go through it to try to learn as much as I can, I apologize for not seeing it earlier

Comment: @user2877858 No worries :). Let me know if you need any clarification with anything.

Comment: how were you able to use *students if it isn't declared in any form?

Comment: It is declared in `student_t *students`. Which line are you confused with?

Comment: You can replace the `malloc()` call with `student_t *students = malloc(n * sizeof(student_t));` if you wish. They both do the same thing, just preference.

Comment: ah I see now, I wasn't confused about any line in particular, but I couldn't see where "students" was declared. I wish I were able to reproduce all this by my own accord, I have an exam in 2 hours :( 

I understood your code very clearly, but the test will have to come from my memory so..rip

Comment: Yeah I'm glad I could help. Just keep the code as simple as possible. Don't overthink the problem, and you should be fine. I'm sure you will do good :).

Answer (score 2):

It appears, `int v[100];` is not quite what you want. Remove that.

You can follow either of two ways.

- [Use a VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). After scanning the value of `n` from user, define the array like `struct students v[n];` and carry on.
- Define a fixed size array, like `struct students v[100];`, and use the size to limit the loop conditions.

That said,

- `scanf("%d", n);` should be `scanf("%d", &n);`, as `%d` expects a pointer to integer type argument for `scanf()`. Same goes for other cases, too.
- `scanf("%s", v[i].name);` should better be `scanf("%19s", v[i].name);` to avoid the possibility of buffer overflow by overly-long inputs.

Comment: That seems to have fixed my initial errors, now I have to allocate the vector in heap using the malloc function thing I think and to go through the vector using pointers, then output the max grade and the students' names, can you help me with that?

Comment: @user2877858 well, a step by step tutorial is out of scope. Please go ahead, write code, if you face any issues, come back and ask a new question. We will be here to help.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you are asking for the number of students (groups) using `scanf`, you hardcoded the upper bound of this value using `v[100]`. So, I passed your input variable `n` (the number of students) to `malloc` in order to allocate the space you need for creating an array of `n` students.

Also, I used `qsort` to sort the input array `v` where the last element would be the `max` value. Here `qsort` accepts an array of structs and deference the pointers passed to the `comp` function to calculate the difference of the comparison.

Finally, I printed the sorted array of structs in the last loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct students {
    int  group;
    char name[20];
    int  grade;
};

int comp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
   return ((((struct students *)a)->grade > ((struct students *)b)->grade) - 
            (((struct students *)a)->grade < ((struct students *)b)->grade));
}

int main()
{
   int n;
   printf("Enter number of groups: ");
   scanf("%d", &n);
   printf("\n");    
   struct students *v = malloc(n * sizeof(struct students));
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
      v[i].group = i;
      printf("\nName: ");
      scanf("%s", v[i].name);
      printf("Grade: ");
      scanf("%d", &v[i].grade);
   }
   qsort(v, n, sizeof(*v), comp);
   for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
      printf("Group %d, Name %s, grade %d\n", v[i].group, v[i].name, v[i].grade);
   }
   return (0);
}
```